# Help decipher a handwritten street name from 1910

Tags: handwriting, kurrent

I'm in a similar situation to the question here [Help deciphering a handwritten marriage record](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/34388/help-deciphering-a-handwritten-marriage-record) and hope this also counts as on-topic.

The image below is from about 1910 and the document was signed in Berlin. The script looks similar to Kurrent, but no matter how many Kurrent examples I look at, I can't even get past the first two letters. I could imagine the start being some form of `Sch...strasse` with a very narrow 'round S' and missing the `c` of `ch`, but not sure if `sch` is even remotely close?

[image]

Apart from the street name itself, I'd be really interested in figuring out the type of script? Is it Kurrent? Is it some regional variation?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

This appears to be **Ohmstraße 6**.

At least one Ohmstraße (named after [Georg Simon Ohm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Georg_Ohm)) [already existed](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liste_der_Stra%C3%9Fen_und_Pl%C3%A4tze_in_Berlin-Siemensstadt#Ohmstra.C3.9Fe.2A) back then and it's one of the very few Berlin street names with such a short name. It seems to be written in [Kurrent](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deutsche_Kurrentschrift) style as you assumed.

Note the somewhat unusual *h* in Kurrent that nicely matches the second letter in your image:

[image]

Comment: That's a great idea, thanks! I thought `O...` before, but the first letter just looks very different to most Kurrent Os I've found?

Comment: @Geotob The *O* is indeed somewhat sloppy. But all the other letters make perfect sense and I find it unlikely that there is another historic Berlin street with such a short and visually similar name.

Comment: there's more interesting info in the same document. It goes on to reference the same street, but number 9. Though according to the 1910 Straube map there was no house with number 9. Have the street numbers changed shortly after 1910?

Comment: @Arminius: I am not saying that Ohmstraße is wrong, but there exist people by the equally short names: Ahm, Ehm, Ihm, Uhm who might have given their name to some street. (Haven't checked whether the respective letters would be a closer match).

Comment: @Arminius I am a bit confused: why did you link to a document from the university in Munich, although the question is about a street in Berlin?

Comment: @Marzipanherz I was looking for the quickest reference and messed up. Thanks for catching that - I have corrected the reference.

Comment: @Geotob The linked wikipedia article mentions that there was a "Kaiserliches Postamt" opened in house number 9 in 1905.